# How to avoid type error when accessing Pandas df.index.reorder_levels()

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, pylance, pyright

I have a Pandas dataframe with a multiindex, so this is valid code:

```py
df.index = df.index.reorder_levels(["B", "A"])
```

But in VS Code (with type checking turned on, set to "basic"), it shows as an error since by default the type of `df.index` is `Index`, not `MultiIndex`.

[image]

I can create a new type just for `MultiIndex` dataframes and use `cast`, but that seems a bit hacky.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        A=[1, 2, 3],
        B=[4, 5, 6],
        C=[4, 5, 6],
    )
).set_index(["A", "B"])


class DataFrameMulti(pd.DataFrame):
    index: pd.MultiIndex


df = typing.cast(DataFrameMulti, df)

df.index = df.index.reorder_levels(["B", "A"])
```

Is there a better way to either:

a) Type the dataframe correctly without having to cast

b) Avoid the type error without turning off other errors?

Edit: to clarify, the problem is not specific to `MultiIndex` or `reorder_levels`, it's about typing any dataframe where the index isn't `Index`. E.g. `DatetimeIndex`:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the first part:
Isn't it only `df.reorder_levels`, see the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html).

so for example:

```
df = df.reorder_levels(['B','A'])
```

for the second part:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1,2,3]), index=pd.date_range("2000-01-01", periods=3))
print(df_test.index.month)
Index([1, 1, 1], dtype='int32')
print(df_test.index.day)
Index([1,2,3], dytpe='int32')
```

it works. I am also on visual studio code.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise that and it solves the instance of the problem I shared. But I still have the problem of how to type a dataframe where the index isn't `Index`. E.g. a DF with a `DatetimeIndex`, VS Code shows `df.index.day` as an error.

Comment: I edited it the first answer

Comment: When you say "it works", do you mean that when you have Type Checking turned on (e.g. `"python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "basic"`) it doesn't show any errors? Or do you just mean that it runs? My issue is the type errors.

Comment: for me it works. See the code above

Comment: What do you mean by "it works". See the comment above. If `df_test.index.bananas` _doesn't_ show a type error for you then you don't have type checking turned on.